# Randomly create turtles in netlogo at the edges of the world

Tags: netlogo

Is there a rather easy procedure which can cluster turtles at the 4 edges of the world?  I'm new at this, and I'd like to have my turtles (flowers) being scattered around the edges.  Thanks so much in advance!!!

```
; creating plants (leaves)
to setup-leaves
create-leaves num-plants [  ; number of plants can vary
rand-xy-co                 ; set random positions for the plants
set shape "flower"         ; initialize the plant to color red and size 2
set color red
set size 2
]
end
```

......

```
to rand-xy-co
  move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor != brown and not any? turtles-here ]
end
```

......

```
;set boundary obstacles. These patches tell the robot to stay within identified bounds.
 ask patches                                
  [
    set pcolor background-colour             ; set colour of background
    if (pxcor >= max-pxcor - boundary-width) ; boundary width can vary
      [ set pcolor brown ]
    if (pxcor <= min-pxcor + boundary-width)
      [ set pcolor brown ]
    if (pycor >= max-pycor - boundary-width)
      [ set pcolor brown ]
    if (pycor <= min-pycor + boundary-width)
      [ set pcolor brown ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your topology does not wrap, you can let your `edge-patches` be `patches with [count neighbors < 8]`.

If your topology wraps, you can let your `edge-patches` be `patches with [member? pxcor (list max-pxcor min-pxcor) or member? pycor (list max-pycor min-pycor)]`.

If you want thicker boundaries, you can just change the lists:

```
to-report edge-patches [#bwidth]
  let offsets n-values #bwidth [?]
  let xvals (reduce sentence map [(list (min-pxcor + ?) (max-pxcor - ?))] offsets)
  let yvals (reduce sentence map [(list (min-pycor + ?) (max-pycor - ?))] offsets)
  report patches with [member? pxcor xvals or member? pycor yvals]
end
```

hth.

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused you in my post....being new to netlogo and I didn't explain it well enough. I want to be able to change the rand-xy-co so that it generates the leaves around the edges.  My topology does not wrap...The way that I understand the edge-patches are the boundary? Or not? [sorry, a bit lost]

Comment: If I understand what you want, you can just `move-to one-of edge-patches 3 with [not any? turtles-here]`, assuming a border-width of 3. (But if you will do this many times, you should store the edge patches in a global, so that you do not repeatedly recreate them.)  Also, don't overlook the possibility of using `sprout`.  For example, if your patches are currently empty, `ask n-of num-plants edge-patches 3 [sprout-leaves 1]` will create `num-plants` leaves, each on its own patch.